# R data: removing rows with NA did not delete the rows

Tags: r

I am trying to remove rows with NA in column 1 (row 4 in the example below), but instead of having the row removed, the entire row 4 is replaced with NA:

```
dat <- data.frame(x1 = c(1,2,3, NA, 5), x2 = c(100, NA, 300, 400, 500))
> dat
#  x1  x2
#  1  1 100
#  2  2  NA
#  3  3 300
#  4 NA 400
#  5  5 500

 ad<- dat[dat$x1!=1,]
 > ad
#     x1  x2
#  2   2  NA
#  3   3 300
#  NA NA  NA
#  5   5 500
```

Comment: `df %>% tidyr::drop_na(x1)`

Comment: `1==NA` returns `NA` and indexing by `NA` gives `NA` - e.g: `c(1)[NA]`

Comment: try this`dat[is.na(dat$x1),]=NA`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `complete.cases`:

```
ad <- dat[complete.cases(dat$x1), ]
```

which will only keep the rows in which dat$x1 does not contain NA